# Vim editor and it's difference and how to repair these editor

Tags: vim, chown, whatsapp, show-desktop, unknown-device

What is difference between  Vi  and Vim in Ubuntu,Because when you type some text in vi it's much differ from what you type in vim .
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Vi is the original "classic" editor. Vim (**V**i **IM**proved) is a version of Vi that has more features. The differing text is likely the configuration of Vim on your system. On full Linux systems, `vi` is generally provided by `busybox`, while `vim` is a package.